# Laravel streaming platform

Tags: laravel, audio-streaming

I am currently working on a streaming platform especially music. The API with Laravel and the front with REACT.JS. My question is how I can set up a streaming server with Laravel or if someone has ever had to work on something similar he could help me with some leads.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hey why not to look at some streaming service like those:

https://rapidapi.com/collection/streaming-apis
or like
https://www.agora.io/en/pricing/

To create a streaming service yourself is not a easy thing ;) . Then you just would have to integrate some of those.

I have worked in the past with Vimeo live events and works fine!

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel for this lead. I'm on it ;)